# Powershell equivalent of MATLAB keyboard() command for debugging?

Tags: powershell, matlab, debugging, keyboard, interactive

MATLAB has a feature to allow users to introduce a command in the script/function called `keyboard` and have the code stop there with a console/command prompt that gives direct access to the interpreter and the variable space. [MATLAB keyboard() command docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html)

Is there something similar in Powershell? I don't want to deal with Powershell ISE as I don't like it's syntax highlighting (doesn't highlight all occurrences of selected phrase like Notepad++ does) and the macros is a lot weaker than what the plain Powershell console itself (like lacking F8 for recalling).

Stepping with a debugger is not quite as useful when you need to explore complex object structures and try a few things out with the current variable states, instead of just reading what the variables and values are in a docked window. It's much easier to work with the state of mind of the interpreted language at any point by interacting with it instead of ploughing through stack and trace information.

Answer (score 1):

In both Powershell ISE and VSCode, you can read or update the same variables in your session from the terminal window at the bottom, even during debugging.